# Why is certbot failing?

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

This is my very first attempt to generate a Letsencrypt certificate:

```
# ufw allow 80
# certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http -d xyz.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for xyz.com
Cleaning up challenges
Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.
```

I've tried some other things too, and I'm not getting anywhere with this.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: you probably have port 80 used by other application, perhaps the one for which you are trying to generate the certificate for. Make sure 80 is available

Comment: Yes, I know for a fact that a web server is listening on port 80, if that's what you mean by "other application."  Also, to make port 80 available, I used the "ufw allow 80" command.

Honestly, I don't have a clear mental model of what is supposed to happen.  When it connects to port 80, what is it supposed to do?  Do I need to set something up there?

Comment: Also trying:

sudo certbot certonly --webroot

...
Input the webroot for xyz.com: (Enter 'c' to cancel):

I don't know what webroot is, but I'm starting to read some instructions about a directory /.well-known/acme-challenge.  I'm not sure what to do with that yet, but I'll try to figure it out.